# Is there some std::count_if() for counting multiple different properties in a single scan?

Tags: c++, std

Is there some `std::count_if`-like function for counting multiple different properties in a single scan?
E.g. it might expect a tuple of function objects and return a tuple of `ptrdiff_t`.
Or the passed function might return a tuple of `bool`.

Comment: nope but you can wrape the std::count_if() function and return all what you need....

Comment: You can probably get away with `std::accumulate`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I'd actually go for `std::reduce` instead, for execution-policy friendliness, which count_if is a good candidate for.

Comment: @Frank Thanks. You're right. I forgot about `std::reduce`.

Comment: Why counting multiple properties should result ina tuple of `bool`s instead of a tuple of `int`s? Furthermore, if the tuple is homogeneous, than `std::tuple` is overkill, and a `std::array` is more appropriate.

Comment: The OP's title reads _counting multiple different properties_. To me that means the result should be "property p1 holds for n objects, property p2 for m objects, ...", which you can easily express as a collection of `int`s, not `bool`s.

Comment: @Enlico I misunderstood your comment, I thought you were proposing a tuple or array of bools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `accumulate`, as suggested:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    // two properties, each returning a bool
    auto constexpr is_even = [](int x){ return x % 2 == 0; };
    auto constexpr is_div_by_3 = [](int x){ return x % 3 == 0; };

    // the function which combines the accumulator with the current value
    auto constexpr lam = [is_even, is_div_by_3](auto a, int x){
        return std::array{a[0] + is_even(x),
                          a[1] + is_div_by_3(x)};
    };

    auto res = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), std::array{0,0}, lam);
    std::cout << res[0] << ' ' << res[1] << std::endl; // prints 5 3
}
```